# C# connect to LTP3 with range E000-E007

Tags: c#, io, parallel-port

I'm using C# to create a software that sends triggers to a special machine connected to the computer in parallel port.

I can't do anything about the hardware there and I'm trying to send numbers via LTP3, and the LTP3 is defined with different range than usual, the range (according to the DeviceManager) is E000-E007.

I'm using c# and I'm trying to send event but it doesn't work. The code I have do work for regular LTP3 and I use 632 as the address (or 888 in case of LTP1).

I really don't understand how it works, what is the correct port? should I change the code?

Here is the part in the code that deals with the sending the events :

```
class PortControl 
{
    [DllImport("inpout32.dll", EntryPoint = "Out32")]
    public static extern void Output(int adress, int value); // decimal
}

private void SendTrigger(int triggerId)
{
    try
    {
        PortControl.Output(632, (short)triggerId);
        Thread.Sleep(1);
        PortControl.Output(632, 0);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error in sending trigger: " + e.Message);
    }
}
```

This work when the LPT3 has a standard range, but not in the this unfamiliar range E000-E007.

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

The address parameter `632` is the decimal equivalent to the hexadecimal value `278`.  Likewise, the hexadecimal value `E000` would have the decimal equivalent of `57344`.

You can pass the address in decimal if you like, but it's much easier to read if you use hexadecimal notation.  Simply prefix the address with `0x`, like so:

```
PortControl.Output(0xE000, ...
```